# Difference between Swift is and isKindOfClass()?

Tags: swift

**Is there any difference between the following expressions?**

```
if someInstance is SomeClass {
}

if someInstance.isKindOfClass(SomeClass)  {
}
```

Comment: The former works with any Swift type. The latter requires that `someInstance` responds to the `isKindOfClass` method (typically achieved by having it be an `NSObject` subclass).

Comment: You can  just look the API document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that the `.isKindOfClass()` is the instance method from Cocoa.

- The right side of `is` can be any type or protocol, whereas the argument of `.isKindOfClass()` must be a reference type (i.e. class). You can also test for conformance to an `@objc` protocol using `.conformsToProtocol()` instead of `.isKindOfClass()` in the same way.
- The left side of `is` is any expression, whereas the receiver of `.isKindOfClass()` must be an object reference. The compiler will complain if the compile-time class of the expression is not known to support `.isKindOfClass()`, but you can overcome this by casting the left side to `AnyObject`. All Swift classes actually support `.isKindOfClass()` at runtime.
- The right side of `is` is a type that must be hard-coded at compile-time. The argument of `.isKindOfClass()` can be a variable or other expression whose value is computed at runtime.

Comment: "a type that must be hard-coded" Yes - you can work around this with `===`, but that is not the same as `is` and I have not found a way to _get_ the same functionality as `is` when what's on the right side is a reference to a class.

Comment: @matt: "and I have not found a way to get the same functionality as is when what's on the right side is a reference to a class." Doesn't `.isKindOfClass()` do exactly that?

Comment: I meant a Swift way. Not everything is Cocoa. Not everything is a class. Not everything inherits from NSObject.

Comment: @matt: You said "when what's on the right side is a reference to a class". `.isKikndOfClass()` works whenever what's on the right side is a class.

Comment: But what about what's on the left side? `class C1 {}; class C2 {};` Now try to use `isKindOfClass()` on `C1()`.

Comment: @matt: `(C1() as AnyObject).isKindOfClass(C2)`

Comment: Because you imported UIKit / Foundation. Cut that import and try it again. And stop being so deliberately contrary! I know you know exactly what I mean. As you said yourself, it's from Cocoa.

Comment: Is there a difference between ``is`` and ``===`` ?

Comment: @SvenBauer: umm... how are they related? `is` is for seeing if something is an instance of a type. `===` defined on object references is for testing if they point to the same object.