# How to use multiple subclasses for function parameter

Tags: swift, swift-class

Say I have 2 subclasses of a class but would like to pass either of those subclasses to a function and determine its type within the function how would that be done?

```
class ParentClass {
  ...
}

class subClass1: ParentClass {
 ...
}

class subClass2: ParentClass {
 ...
}

function getClassType(type: ParentClass) {
   return(type)
}

viewDidLoad...
getClassType(type: subClass2())
```

Comment: Is the parent class a subclass of NSObject, or is it a pure Swift class?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31231022/difference-between-swift-is-and-iskindofclass). Pretty much summarize the issue.

Comment: Ariel thanks the "is" keyword was what I needed. I can mark your answer if you post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ariel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/821446/ariel) beat me to it but since i can't mark posts as duplicate yet ill post the answer.

The way to check if an object is op type is with the `is` keywoard:

```
if type is subClass1 {
    // Do stuff
}
```